# Enabling search feature in google maps using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-location-services

I was trying to implement a simple search bar in google maps that points the map's camera to the location that is entered in the search box, I've attached the code but whenever I run it, The application ends up crashing. The code is given below. (Also I'm new to Android Development, Please do help me out).

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1009;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    //These Clusters were used to manage the marker Clusters that had images on maps too
    private ClusterManager mClusterManager;
    //Same is the case with these clusters
    private MyClusterManagerRenderer myClusterManagerRenderer;
    //Instantiating the Firestore Database
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    // creating a variable
    // for search view.
    SearchView searchView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initializing our search view.
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.idSearchView);

        // initializing our firebase firestore.
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        //Getting the device location over here
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //***** Searching Part starts from here*********
        // adding on query listener for our search view.
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // on below line we are getting the
                // location name from search view.
                String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();

                // below line is to create a list of address
                // where we will store the list of all address.
                List<Address> addressList = null;

                // checking if the entered location is null or not.
                if (location != null || location.equals("")) {
                    // on below line we are creating and initializing a geo coder.
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                    try {
                        // on below line we are getting location from the
                        // location name and adding that location to address list.
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // on below line we are getting the location
                    // from our list a first position.
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);

                    // on below line we are creating a variable for our location
                    // where we will add our locations latitude and longitude.
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                    // on below line we are adding marker to that position.
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));

                    // below line is to animate camera to that position.
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        // at last we calling our map fragment to update.
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }



    private void addMapMarkers(){

    }




    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Location location = task.getResult();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // creating a variable for document reference.
        DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("MapsData").document("7QWDor9vozLaHdFYV9kh");

        // calling document reference class with on snap shot listener.
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (value != null && value.exists()) {
                    // below line is to create a geo point and we are getting
                    // geo point from firebase and setting to it.
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = value.getGeoPoint("geoPoint");

                    // getting latitude and longitude from geo point
                    // and setting it to our location.
                    LatLng location = new LatLng(geoPoint.getLatitude(), geoPoint.getLongitude());

                    // adding marker to each location on google maps
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Name"));

                    // below line is use to move camera.
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Error found is " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        //Adding custom maps style over here
        //******** THIS PART OF CODE EXCLUSIVELY DESIGNED TO FETCH THE CUSTOM MAPS.JSON TEMPLATE**********
        enableMyLocation();

        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.mapstyle));
            if (!success) {
                Log.e("MapsActivity", "Style parsing failed.");
            }
            } catch (Resources. NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("MapsActivity", "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }
        //******** MAP STYLING CODE ENDS OVER HERE **********



        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        LatLng islamabad = new LatLng(33.68, 73.04);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Islamabad"));
        //moving the camera position to Islamabad.
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(islamabad));


    }

    //Getting the Users current Location

    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // Check if location permissions are granted and if so enable the
        // location data layer.
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0]
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    enableMyLocation();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing a SearchView, add the places API from google in your grade file as follows:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0'
```

and use AutocompleteSupportFragment as follows:

```
try {
                    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
                        Places.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), GlobalVariables.google_api_key);
                    }
  // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        
        autocompleteFragment.getView().setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.bginfo_whit));
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
        autocompleteFragment.setCountry("ET");
        autocompleteFragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
             @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                    LatLng newLatLng = place.getLatLng();
                     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLatLng));
                     mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
                    }

            @Override
                 public void onError(Status status) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                     //Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
                    }

                 });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I've managed to add the fragment but it's not showing me the data regarding the places... Should I share my code regarding this?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadNawazMalik I forgot to mention that you have to add/ enable the Places API in the Google Cloud Platform, to do that follow this link (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)  and click on the Get Started button. If that doesn't work feel free to share what you have tried.